# FEEL Grammar: How to refer to context entries specified by a string literal grammar rule?

Tags: grammar, decision-model-notation

A `context entry` & `key` are defined by the following grammar (cf DMN v1.2, page 111, Section 10.3.1.2)

```
60. context entry = key , ":", expression;
61. key = name | string literal;
```

Consider the following instance of a context object

```
{ "12" : "hello" }
```

How do I access `"hello"` from such an object?

Could this be an issue in the grammar? Not sure if this kind of accession is valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accordingly to [DMN specification](https://www.omg.org/spec/DMN/1.2/PDF), as "12" cannot be transformed into a legal name I concur with you, cannot be accessed with the dot operator.

But you can use the built-in function `get value()` as for the spec:

> If key1 is not a legal name or for whatever reason one wishes to treat
>   the key as a string, the following syntax is allowed: get value(m,
>   "key1").

For example:

```
get value({ "12" : "hello" }, "12")
```

this is valid FEEL and would result in `"hello"`.

I see no issue in the grammar.
I believe the only way to access this entry value is by using the built-in function.